# For every complex and not real number $z$: $A - zI $ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

struggling with the following question, thinking about using hermitian matrix properties, but get lost on the way...

Given the following matrix:

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 5 & 5\\ 
5 & -2 & 5\\ 
 5& 5 & -2
\end{pmatrix}$

For every complex and not real number  $z$:
 $A - zI $ is invertible.

Comment: Eigenvalues of a hermitian matrix are real, and $A$ is hermitian.

Comment: Hey, Sorry, can't understand - why that implies  $A - zI $ in invertible?

Comment: @LioH What are the eigenvalues of $A-zI$? Say if $Av = \lambda v$ then $(A-zI)v = ?$

Comment: Putting aside clever methods using properties of Hermitian matrices - if stuck, why can't you simply compute the characteristic polynomial, find its roots (one of which is quite obvious by the appearance of the matrix) and verify that they are real?

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. because $A$ has only real eigenvalues and  $z$ is complex,  $det(A - zI) $ is non-zero, which means $(A - zI) $  is invertible. Thanks!